# Google Analytics 'Mobile Device Model' and Android's Build.MODEL

Tags: android, google-analytics

Is there any way to obtain 'Mobile Device Model' parameter on Android that is posted to Google Analytics? Build.MODEL constant mismatches 'Mobile Device Model', that is displayed on Google Analytics web page in certain cases. For example, for Huawei Nova, 'Mobile Device Model' is 'CAN-L11', and Build.MODEL equals 'Huawei CAN-L11'.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems 'Mobile Device Model' is unusable in my case. The only way to get Google Analytics to work correctly is using events labels with Build.MODEL. You shoot two rabbits at once: reports become more detailed (earlier with 'Mobile Device Model' reports contained only 10% of overall collected data) and you get reusable data.

Answer (score 2):

This cool and small library returns the commercial name based on the Build.MODEL and Build.DEVICE.  https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidDeviceNames

Internally it uses this Google's maintained list with over 10K devices (which probably uses GA as well):
https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131?hl=en

In case there is no automatic way to get the build model string used by Google Analytics, you might create your own solution using these sources.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to reuse Google Analytics data in my app. It's not related to showing nice product name.